# How to use existing SBT installation instead of downloading a new one in intelij?

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea

I'm using os x and I've installed sbt with brew. After I've installed intellij and scala plugin for intellij it recognized .scala files of my project and suggested to import sbt project. When importing I saw that intellij is downloading sbt instead of using sbt installation that I have installed previously. How to force intellij to use sbt from brew? I don't want to clutter my ssd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a wise decision. sbt API changes slightly between versions. If intellij requires certain version for inner processing, it would be better to fulfil its expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Set `sbt.version` in `project/build.properties`. IntelliJ respects the requested version. It won't download again if it has already been downloaded. You probably see this because the launcher you installed is a different version than what is installed in intellij. You can also set intellij to use the launcher you already have installed by changing the setting in preferences

Comment: And on that note, you'll likely run several versions of sbt when working with different projects. There is very little point in fighting this.